# Standard way to notate string/fret/finger?

Tags: notation, composition, fingering

(Mandolin)

As a composer, say I want to notate that musician should play the Bb that is on the D string at eighth fret with 4th finger. Is there a standard notation? I don't mean TAB. More like D.8 (4) or like that?

This would apply to other fretted instruments like guitar too.

Answer (score 1):

In standard notation, for fretted string instruments, left hand fingers are usually indicated with small numbers near the note heads, see https://goo.gl/images/6ixrEm

For guitar, the string is sometimes indicated with a circled number above/below the note, c.f. https://goo.gl/images/3WyX0g, but usually this is only done in teaching materials.  Outside teaching materials, this type of marking almost never present.  For guitar, given the (left-hand) fingerings, and the context there is almost never any ambiguity about which string is required (for mandolin, where the frets are closer together there might be more opportunity for ambiguity).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I know that. I suppose the player should know from context which string that should be on?

Comment: @EricO updated to address comment

Answer (score 0):

The mandolin fingering follows (for the most part) the violin fingering.

Playing the bflat on the D string with the 4th finger puts you in second position. Putting a 4 above the note should tell the mandolinist the position to use by context, but if you want to be sure there are a few ways:

Put a roman numeral III at the passage to indicate it is played on the D or 3rd string.

Write Sul D before the passage indicating it is played on the D string.

Use the term "2 pos", which I have seen, but don't recommend.